# Why does phpmailer take 15+ seconds to load?

Tags: php, iis

I recently setup phpmailer as my SMTP sending script to use for a website I've been working on and it's been nothing but a headache. My setup is IIS, and I'm currently using office365 to send out emails(although I have tried gmail and the results were no faster).I would appreciate any and all advice on how to speed this up, or if there's a way to post to a php file from javascript or php and then just let it work I could do that too. I'm trying to stay away from cron jobs if possible.

my script:

```
function sendMail($code, $email) {
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 587;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "support@[domain redacted].com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "[password redacted]";
//enable TLS
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('support@[domain redacted].com', '[redacted]');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('support@[domain redacted].com', '[redacted]');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($email);
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'This is a test email from EdTester Support';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to     embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->Body = "Hello there, This is your activation e-mail. Please go to:         http://[domain redacted]/activate.php?code=". $code . "&email="     . $email;
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably the latency between your server and the external host. Add some microtime statements before and after the send and retrun to see how long the service taking to respond. If it is network latency then there is not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: I'll try doing a localhost SMTP server and if I can still get that issue I'll try the microtime statements